# Stop duplicate icmp echo replies when bridging to a dummy interface?

Tags: linux, bridge, icmp

I recently configured a bridge `br0` with members as `eth0` (real `if`) and `dummy0` (`dummy.ko` `if`).

When I ping this machine, I receive duplicate replies as:

```
  # ping SERVERA
  PING SERVERA.domain.local (192.168.100.115) 56(84) bytes of data.
  64 bytes from SERVERA.domain.local (192.168.100.115): icmp_seq=1 ttl=62 time=113 ms
  64 bytes from SERVERA.domain.local (192.168.100.115): icmp_seq=1 ttl=62 time=114 ms (DUP!)
  64 bytes from SERVERA.domain.local (192.168.100.115): icmp_seq=2 ttl=62 time=113 ms
  64 bytes from SERVERA.domain.local (192.168.100.115): icmp_seq=2 ttl=62 time=113 ms (DUP!)
```

Using `tcpdump` on `SERVERA`, I was able to see icmp echo replies being sent from `eth0` and `br0` itself as follows (oddly two echo request packets arrive "from" my Windows box `myhost`):

```
  23:19:05.324192 IP myhost.domain.local > SERVERA.domain.local: ICMP echo request, id 512, seq 43781, length 40
  23:19:05.324212 IP SERVERA.domain.local > myhost.domain.local: ICMP echo reply, id 512, seq 43781, length 40
  23:19:05.324217 IP myhost.domain.local > SERVERA.domain.local: ICMP echo request, id 512, seq 43781, length 40
  23:19:05.324221 IP SERVERA.domain.local > myhost.domain.local: ICMP echo reply, id 512, seq 43781, length 40
  23:19:05.324264 IP SERVERA.domain.local > myhost.domain.local: ICMP echo reply, id 512, seq 43781, length 40
  23:19:05.324272 IP SERVERA.domain.local > myhost.domain.local: ICMP echo reply, id 512, seq 43781, length 40
```

It's worth noting, testing reveals that hosts on the same physical switch do not see DUP `icmp echo responses` (a host on the same VLAN on another switch does see a dup `icmp echo response`).

I've read that this could be due to the `ARP` table of a switch, but I can't find any info directly related to `bridges`, just `bonds`.  I have a feeling my problem lay in the stack on linux, not the switch, but am opened to any suggestions.

The system is running centos6/el6 kernel `2.6.32-71.29.1.el6.i686`.

How do I stop ICMP echo replies from being sent in duplicate when dealing with a bridge interface/bridged interfaces?

Thanks,

Matt

***[edit]***

Quick note:
It was recommended in #linux to:

```
[08:53] == mbrownnyc [gateway/web/freenode/] has joined ##linux
[08:57] <lkeijser> mbrownnyc: what happens if you set arp_ignore to 1 for the dummy interface?
[08:59] <lkeijser> also set arp_announce to 2 for that interface
[09:24] <mbrownnyc> lkeijser: I set arp_annouce to 2, arp_ignore to 2 in /etc/sysctl.conf and rebooted the machine... verifying that the bits are set after boot... the problem is still present
```

I did this and came up empty. Same dup problem.

I will be moving away from including the dummy interface in the bridge as:

```
[09:31] == mbrownnyc [gateway/web/freenode/] has joined #Netfilter
[09:31] <mbrownnyc> Hello all... I'm wondering, is it correct that even with an interface in PROMISC that the kernel will drop /some/ packets before they reach applications?
[09:31] <whaffle> What would you make think so?
[09:32] <mbrownnyc> I ask because I am receiving ICMP echo replies after configuring a bridge with a dummy interface in order for ipt_netflow to see all packets, only as reported in it's documentation: http://ipt-netflow.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=ipt-netflow/ipt-netflow;a=blob;f=README.promisc
[09:32] <mbrownnyc> but I do not know if PROMISC will do the same job
[09:33] <mbrownnyc> I was referred here from #linux.  any assistance is appreciated
[09:33] <whaffle> The following conditions need to be met: PROMISC is enabled (bridges and applications like tcpdump will do this automatically, otherwise they won't function).
[09:34] <whaffle> If an interface is part of a bridge, then all packets that enter the bridge should already be visible in the raw table.
[09:35] <mbrownnyc> thanks whaffle PROMISC must be set manually for ipt_netflow to function, but
[09:36] <whaffle> promisc does not need to be set manually, because the bridge will do it for you.
[09:36] <whaffle> When you do not have a bridge, you can easily create one, thereby rendering any kernel patches moot.
[09:36] <mbrownnyc> whaffle: I speak without the bridge
[09:36] <whaffle> It is perfectly valid to have a "half-bridge" with only a single interface in it.
[09:36] <mbrownnyc> whaffle: I am unfamiliar with the raw table, does this mean that PROMISC allows the raw table to be populated with packets the same as if the interface was part of a bridge?
[09:37] <whaffle> Promisc mode will cause packets with {a dst MAC address that does not equal the interface's MAC address} to be delivered from the NIC into the kernel nevertheless.
[09:37] <mbrownnyc> whaffle: I suppose I mean to clearly ask: what benefit would creating a bridge have over setting an interface PROMISC?
[09:38] <mbrownnyc> whaffle: from your last answer I feel that the answer to my question is "none," is this correct?
[09:39] <whaffle> Furthermore, the linux kernel itself has a check for {packets with a non-local MAC address}, so that packets that will not enter a bridge will be discarded as well, even in the face of PROMISC.
[09:46] <mbrownnyc> whaffle: so, this last bit of information is quite clearly why I would need and want a bridge in my situation
[09:46] <mbrownnyc> okay, the ICMP echo reply duplicate issue is likely out of the realm of this channel, but I sincerely appreciate the info on the kernels inner-workings
[09:52] <whaffle> mbrownnyc: either the kernel patch, or a bridge with an interface. Since the latter is quicker, yes
[09:54] <mbrownnyc> thanks whaffle
```

***[edit2]***

After removing the bridge, and removing the dummy kernel module, I only had a single interface chilling out, lonely.  I still received duplicate icmp echo replies... in fact I received a random amount: http://pastebin.com/2LNs0GM8

The same thing doesn't happen on a few other hosts on the same switch, so it has to do with the linux box itself.  I'll likely end up rebuilding it next week.  Then... you know... this same thing will occur again.

***[edit3]***
Guess what?  I rebuilt the box, and I'm still receiving duplicate ICMP echo replies.  Must be the network infrastructure, although the ARP tables do not contain multiple entries.

***[edit4]***
How ridiculous.

The machine was a network probe, so I was (ingress and egress) mirroring an uplink port to a node that was the NIC.  So, the flow (must have) gone like this:

1. `ICMP echo request` comes in through the `mirrored uplink port`.
2. (the real) `ICMP echo request` is received by the NIC
3. (the mirrored) `ICMP echo request` is received by the NIC
4. `ICMP echo reply` is sent for both.

I'm ashamed of myself, but now I know.  It was suggested on `#networking` to either isolate the mirrored traffic to an interface that does not have IP enabled.  Another solution is to create an administrative VLAN, and remove the mirroring of packets to the administrative VLAN (unfortunately, not an option on my switch).

Comment: Can you show us the results of `ifconfig`? It is my initial suspicion that you assigned the same IP address to both interfaces that are part of the bridge.

Comment: Thanks Jeff: http://pastebin.com/DTJQAH6d  Both of them have "no" IPv4 address.

Answer (score 2):

I see. What you're looking for is a bond. What you've got with your bridge is multiple interfaces that all act independently on packets they receive having inherited the address of the bridge interface. This is good when you're connecting two network switches through your machine. When you've got them both hooked to the same switch, you see this behavior of multiple replies.

Bonds, on the other hand, offer a behavior that ensures that only one car in the bond will handle traffic. This can be through active / passive failover, bonding with the switch, or rotating through cards depending on how you configure the bond interface.

You switch isn't really part of the equation here since you only have one cable linked to the bond interface.

Comment: "When you've got them both hooked to the same switch, you see this behavior of multiple replies." I am using a `dummy` interface (with the kernel module `dummy.ko`).  Why would I ||`bond`|| a real interface with a `dummy` interface?  It was my understanding that bridged interfaces are just that, a bridge; so wouldn't it pass the same traffic to all members of `br0`?  This is the problem?  I'm concerned that the kernel will drop certain packets that arrive at the real interface before they traverse the stack unless (of course) there's a bridge involving the real interface and another interface?

Comment: Can I do [this (see solution 2)](http://ipt-netflow.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=ipt-netflow/ipt-netflow;a=blob;f=README.promisc) with a bond?

Comment: @mbrownnyc Usually with something this complex I spin up a few virtual machines and test it before opening my mouth. Today I'm a little bit behind the curve on things... I'll try and come up with a test soon.

Comment: Thanks for your help Jeff!  Also to mention, the `dummy` interface has the `noarp` flag set.

Comment: Just did some more testing, hosts on the same switch do not see DUP `icmp echo responses`.

Answer (score 1):

I made a clone of VM (with VMware) and I got the same problem.
The networking card, from the new VM, had new MAC address.
There is a way to fix it, (I already did this in the past) but because I was in a hurry.
I delete the new VM and when I clone again, with the old MAC address, everything was OK.